# Is Must really an Auxiliary Verb?

Tags: modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Can we use short answers as a proving method for modal verbs? The rule regarding the short answer to affirmative or negative statements is to repeat the auxiliary verb. eg:
*"I **can** fly."

  "So **can** I."


"I **shouldn't** stop eating."

  "Neither **should** I."*

I was taught that **"Have to"** is not a Modal Auxiliary Verb because it fails this test. eg: 
*"I **have** **to** run."

  "So **do** I."*

But what about **Must**? 
*"I **must** be getting old."

  "So **must** I."


"I **must** be crazy!"

  "So **must** I!"*

Is that really correct? It seems strange to me, but I'd accept it if someone could show evidence to support it. My inclination is to find ways around saying this, but maybe that's out of fear of sounding like a character from Lord of the Rings. I guess this is where "me too" comes in to save the day.

Comment: But (for me at least, perhaps because I'm British, and getting on a bit), ***So have I*** is a perfectly acceptable response to ***I have to go now***. In any case, I think your "rule" for identifying auxiliary verbs is really just a "rule **of thumb**" (it's probably not a *definitive* rule that will give the "right" classification in every case).

Comment: Note that from the linguist's point of view, ***to have to*** (*be obliged to*, usually pronounced ***HAFF***) is effectively ***a different "word"*** to the one used as an auxiliary to create Perfect verb forms and so on. Also from the (subconscious) perspective of many native speakers - that's ***why*** we pronounce it differently.

Comment: Of course it's an auxiliary verb. What else could it possibly be? Hint: auxiliary verbs are those with the NICE properties. Check the 'Net for tons of info on this, e.g. [link](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/verbs/nice.htm)

Comment: Further: when "have" occurs in clauses expressing obligation usage can be divided. Most speakers treat it as a lexical verb, but some treat it as as auxiliary, cf. "Have I to sign both forms?" (aux) vs "Do I have to sign both forms?" (lexical).

Comment: **So must I** could not be more correct. Just like **might**: I might go tomorrow. **So might he**. And **may**. He may leave early tonight. So **may I**. Careful with mustn't: He mustn't find out. Neither must they.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes.

An auxiliary verb (abbreviated aux) is a verb that adds functional or grammatical meaning to the clause in which it appears, so as to express tense, aspect, modality, voice, emphasis, etc. Auxiliary verbs usually accompany a main verb.

[source: wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb)

"must" has 2 functions: deontic modality

> You must not mock me.

and epistemic modality

> It must have rained.

as for your question,

> "I must be crazy!"
>
> "I must be getting old."

Both correspond to epistemic modality.

So, "must" is an auxiliary verb.

Comment: "deontic modality" and "epistemic modality" are probably too much for English learners. I don't even know what they mean as a native speaker!

Comment: simply speaking, epistemic modality means inference, conclusion.

Comment: I don't think it's commonly taught, @CJDennis, but I find myself referring to the two meanings (deontic and epistemic) of modals frequently in answering questions here.

Comment: It bears noting that lexical verbs can also have modal meanings, e.g. "You **need** to leave".

Answer (score -1):

Auxiliaries are important in spoken conversation because the patterns with them are regularly used in it. They are used instead of repetition of lexical verbs in short answers. The syntax with a modal verb 'must' is governed with the so called the auxiliary pattern. The complexity of using auxiliary pattern of the modal verb 'must' is that some short answers with it needs some change of modal verbs.
For example,  He must be a brother of this student. No, he can't be.

As for your question, a useful link
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254021/so-must-i-or-so-do-i-in-place-of-of-course/25403

Comment: Person 1: He must be this student's brother. Person 2: Yes, he must. Only in the negative does it change. Person 2: No, he can't be.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: However there is no prohibition against using "he must not be" *per se*.  See these [examples](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1975%2Ccd_max%3A2019%2Clr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk007jAbT6KyJMTm-21mgm1sBAlhwrQ%3A1605881513694&ei=qc63X8ryKami1fAPhc2-oA8&q=%22he+must+not+be%22&oq=%22he+must+not+be%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...62335.63115.0.65037.3.3.0.0.0.0.129.248.2j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.y3dsl2lDwXk)